# Creating a matrix based on time series at different locations in R

Tags: r, matrix, social-networking

I am looking to create a function to create a matrix based on movement of numerous unique individual ID's on different dates to different locations.

In essence I am looking to count the number of movements by individuals between locations. With each movement counting as 1. as I am only hoping to look at movement the first location would not count as 1 but the movement between the first and second date would count as 1 and if the individual stayed where it was it would not count as a movement.

An example data-frame would be (except I have n of individuals and  n locations):

```
individual <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
locations <- c("L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L3", "L2", "L1", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L3", "L3", "L1")
date <- c("12/04/2018", "13/04/2018", "14/04/2018", "15/04/2018", "16/04/2018", "12/04/2018", "13/04/2018", "14/04/2018", "15/04/2018", "16/04/2018", "12/04/2018", "13/04/2018", "14/04/2018", "15/04/2018", "16/04/2018")
df <- data.frame(individual, date, locations)
df$individual <- as.factor(df$individual)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

I am trying to create an output that would look similar to this:

```
B = matrix( 
  c(0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
  nrow=3, ncol=3
)
colnames(B) = c("L1_moved_to", "L2_moved_to", "L3_moved_to")
rownames(B) = c("L1_moved_from", "L2_moved_from", "L3_moved_from")
```

I am hoping to then graph this matrix but I am finding it hard to create the initial matrix in `R`

**EDIT**

using my data when I look at the output from `df_change_with_lag_drop_initial` i get:

```
individual1 <- c("b1316", "b1316")
location1 <- c(5, 1)
loc_lag1    <- c(4, 5)
df1 <- data.frame(individual1, location1, loc_lag1)
```

however, when you look at the raw data it looks like this:

```
individual2 <- c("b1316", "b1316", "b1316", "b1316", "b1316", "b1316")
location2 <- c(4, 5, 4, 1, 5, 4)
date2   <- c("07/01/2012", "18/02/2012", "04/01/2013", "03/01/2014", "07/01/2016", "18/02/2017")
df2 <- data.frame(individual2, date2, location2)
df2$individual2 <- as.factor(df2$individual2)
df2$date2 <- as.Date(df2$date2, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df2$location2 <- as.factor(df2$location2)
```

so as I had mentioned the score should show 5 movements (1, 1, 1, 1, 1) but the loc_lag output is - 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 - so only showing movements between locations that are new.

Comment: maybe you're not using the updated code? this shows 5 movements: `df2[ , lag_loc := shift(location2), by = individual2
     ][location2 != lag_loc,
       dcast(.SD, lag_loc ~ location2, fill = 0,
            value.var = 'individual2', fun.aggregate = length)]`

Comment: b1316 is in this data set

Comment: @MichaelChirico I think I have identified the problem but unsure about how to fix it. When that section of the code runs it identifies the five changes. however, something happens during `df2[ , row_change_id := rowid(individual2, location2)][]` when it converts/ranks them and factors (site numbers) which have been used before dont come up as new movements. when you look at the outputs from df2 once `df2[ , row_change_id := rowid(individual2, location2)][]` runs you can see that the `row_change_id` are not 1 were they should be but instead 2/3 as if the individual had been in the same place.

Comment: again I'm not sure you're using the updated answer... I don't use rowid anymore

Comment: apologies. you are right. thank you so much for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this quite succinctly with `data.table` as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[ , lag_loc := shift(locations), by = individual
    ][locations != lag_loc,
      dcast(.SD, lag_loc ~ locations, fill = 0,
            value.var = 'individual', fun.aggregate = length)]
#    loc_lag L1 L2 L3
# 1:      L1  0  2  0
# 2:      L2  1  0  1
# 3:      L3  1  0  0
```

Broken down into steps:

Load `data.table`; convert `df` to a `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)
```

Find which rows correspond to change of `locations`:

```
df[ , lag_loc := shift(locations), by = individual][]
#    individual       date locations lag_loc
#  1:          1 2018-04-12        L1    <NA>
#  2:          1 2018-04-13        L2      L1
#  3:          1 2018-04-14        L2      L2
#  4:          1 2018-04-15        L2      L2
#  5:          1 2018-04-16        L3      L2
#  6:          2 2018-04-12        L2    <NA>
#  7:          2 2018-04-13        L1      L2
#  8:          2 2018-04-14        L1      L1
#  9:          2 2018-04-15        L2      L1
# 10:          2 2018-04-16        L2      L2
# 11:          3 2018-04-12        L3    <NA>
# 12:          3 2018-04-13        L3      L3
# 13:          3 2018-04-14        L3      L3
# 14:          3 2018-04-15        L3      L3
```

Subset `df` to only rows corresponding to `location` changes:

```
df_change = df[locations != lag_loc]
```

Reshape this table wide as `origin ~ destination`; `fill = 0` means that any `origin`->`destination` combination not represented will show up as 0 (especially along the diagonal). `value.var` doesn't really matter here, but `individual` is pretty intuitive since it has the interpretation of -- as we reshape, we apply `fun.aggregate` to all rows within the same combination of `origin` and `destination`, i.e. each cell in the output should be `length(individual)` for each O-D combination, which should be clear-ish to see counts the number of such individuals:

```
dcast(df_change, loc_lag ~ locations, fill = 0,
      value.var = 'individual', fun.aggregate = length)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer it is great and nearly what I am looking for. The added information all the way through is amazing. The 2 comes from the movement of individual 1 from line 1 - 2 and from individual 2 from line 8 -9 in your code: df[ , row_change_id := rowid(individual, locations)][]. in your sig_id not line 8 and 9 are 2 but line 9 should be a 1.

Comment: @DFinch indeed my initial answer was mistaken, I thought I covered the case that I failed to. Fixed now.

Comment: that is brilliant. I have been looking through my data and there seems to be something else up. if the location has already been used it seems to drop it from the rest of the grouping even though the individual may go back there again. what I mean is e.g. if you take these as the location ID's (4, 5, 4, 1, 5, 4) and then the individual is moving through them it should look like - 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 - in terms of movement scores but what I think the code is doing is give - 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 - as the output. does that make sense? thank you for all of your help. it is much appreciated.

Comment: @DFinch I'm not sure I follow, could you include this in the example in your question?